# Reversing string with COBOL

Tags: cobol

I am trying to reverse given string in COBOL.

**IBM documentation**
I refered to IBM documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.1?topic=functions-transforming-reverse-order-reverse

**This is my code** which expects to take string and return its reversed version:

```
       identification division.
       program-id. solution.
       data division.
       linkage section.
       01  str.
           05 len      pic 99.
           05 chars    pic a(30).
       01  result.
           05 len      pic 99.
           05 chars    pic a(30).
       procedure division using str result.
          move function reverse(str) to result.
          goback.
       end program solution.
```

**Outcome from the test (example)** - taking string "hello", return nothing

```
Testing "hello"                                                                                     
Expected and actual have different lengths
expected: 5
actual:
```

**TEST**
This is test I am using to verify my function:

```
       identification division.
       program-id. tests.

       data division.
       working-storage section.
       01  a-disp      pic z(7)9.
       01  b-disp      pic z(7)9.
       01  expected.
           05  len     pic 99.
           05  chars   pic a(30).
       01  str.
           05  len     pic 99.
           05  chars   pic a(20).
       01  result.
           05  len     pic 99.
           05  chars   pic a(30).

       procedure division.
           testsuite 'Fixed Tests.'.
           move 'world' to chars of str
           move length of 'world' to len of str
           move 'dlrow' to chars of expected
           move length of 'dlrow' to len of expected
           perform dotest

           move 'hello' to chars of str
           move length of 'hello' to len of str
           move 'olleh' to chars of expected
           move length of 'olleh' to len of expected
           perform dotest
           
           move 0 to len of str
           move 0 to len of expected
           perform dotest

           move 'h' to chars of str
           move length of 'h' to len of str
           move 'h' to chars of expected
           move length of 'h' to len of expected
           perform dotest

           end tests.

       dotest.
           testcase 'Testing ' '"' chars of str(1:len of str) '"'.
           call 'solution' using str result
           evaluate len of result
               when <> len of expected
                   move len of result to a-disp
                   move len of expected to b-disp
                   initialize assertion-message
                   string 'Expected and actual have different lengths' 
                      line-feed
                      'expected: ' function trim(b-disp)
                      line-feed
                      'actual:   ' function trim(a-disp)
                       into assertion-message
                   perform assert-false
               when 0
                   initialize assertion-message
                   perform assert-true
               when other
                   expect chars of result(1:len of result) 
                          to be 
                          chars of expected(1:len of expected).
           end-evaluate
           .

       end program tests.
```

Comment: Explains "which fails"?

Comment: Can you create a [mre] ?   (Your current code is not, see: https://onlinegdb.com/2dRWR7FUT )

Comment: @not2savvy - I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course this doesn't work. [`FUNCTION REVERSE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=functions-reverse) takes a "string", not a group with length and "string".

Either use `FUNCTION REVERSE (str(1:len))` or truncate by [`FUNCTION TRIM`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=functions-trim) instead of passing a length, simply coding `FUNCTION REVERSE (FUNCTION TRIM (str))`.